# SE for point estimate

Tags: confidence-interval, regression-coefficients, standard-error

So suppose I regressed y on x1 and x2 (where x2 is a factor variable with values 0 and 1).

And I wish to obtain confidence interval for the ratio of  estimated y's for different x2 values for the same value of x1.

So my point estimate would be = (slope(x2) * 1 + intercept + slope(x1) * mean(x1)) / (intercept + slope(x1) * mean(x1))

Is it correct?

And for SE for confidence interval of my point estimate, would I just choose SE for x1 in regression output?

Comment: Unclear. "slope(x2)*1"; 1 what? "intercept" of what? Put in models, e.g., $$y-y_0=m_1(x_1-x_0)$$ or $$y-y_0=m_1(x_1-x_0)+m_2(x_2-b_2)$$ and note you may not be able to separate effects quite the way you think at first blush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you fit the model, I assume you can get the 3x3 estimated variance-covariance matrix of the $\hat \beta$. Suppose your sample size is not too small (<50). Then use the delta method to get the approximation of variance of that estimated ratio. Square root of the approximated variance is the approximated SE. Based on the normal approximation, you can get CI.

If it is hard for you to finish the delta method in one step, you can seperate it into two steps:

1. Calculate the variances of the numerator and denominator and the covariance between them (most statistical softwares provide them).
2. Use the delta method on the ratio of two random variables. (This is common method in statistics and I believe you can find solution on internet).